# socket rooms doesn't work

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to create a private tchat room using the concept of socket.io rooms.  When the user clicks on a name of another user, a comparaison will start,if there is a room which contains both users, then it will join the room, otherwise a new room with both users will be created.
When a message arrives, the message is sent to the corrsponding room, but my code doesn't work: the comparaison is done, the corresponding ids are found, but the messages are send for everyone connected to the tchat.

Here is the code of the server

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

//session-store


var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
require('./config/passport')(passport);


var Room = require('./app/models/room');
var User = require('./app/models/user');

//session
var sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret: 'anystringoftext',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
  }),

  ttl: 2 * 24 * 60 * 60
});
//fonction btoa
var btoa = require('btoa');
var atob = require('atob');

//session with socket.io
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

      socket.on('startchat', function(name) {

        //my id
        var idUser = socket.request.session.passport.user;
        //search for my name
        User.findById(idUser, function(err, user) {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (user) {
            //my name
            nameUser = user.local.username;


            if (name < nameUser) {
              var users = name + ',' + nameUser;
            } else {
              var users = nameUser + ',' + name;
            }
            //encrypt the string
            var roomid = btoa(users);

            //searching fo ra corresponding id
            Room.find(function(err, room) {
              if (err) throw err;
              if (room) {
                var dRoom = '';
                room.forEach(function(room) {


                  var idRoom = atob(room.id).split(',');
                  //comparaison

                  if ((idRoom[0] == nameUser && idRoom[1] == name) || (idRoom[0] == name && idRoom[1] == nameUser)) {
                    dRoom = room.id;
                    console.log(idRoom, room.id);
                    //join the room
                    socket.join(dRoom);
                  }
                });

                if (dRoom == '') {
                  //we didn't find an id which corresponds so we create a room with this id
                  dRoom = roomid;
                  var newroom = new Room({
                    id: roomid
                  });
                  newroom.save();
                  console.log('created');
                  console.log(atob(roomid).split(','));
                  console.log(roomid);
                  //join the room
                  socket.join(roomid);
                }

              }

              //when msg is emitted
              socket.on('message', function(msg) {
                console.log('message', dRoom);
                //emit the msgs to this room
                io.sockets.in(dRoom).emit('msg', msg);
              });
            });

          }

        });


      });

      app.use(express.static('public'));

      app.use(morgan('dev'));
      app.use(cookieParser());
      app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
      }));
      app.use(sessionMiddleware);
      //passport and sessions

      app.use(passport.initialize());
      app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
      app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session


      app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

      require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);

      server.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('Server running on port: ' + port);
      });
```

the client.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var socket = io();

  socket.on('connect', function() {
   // Connected, let's sign-up for to receive messages for this room
   $('#chat').hide();

   var start;
   window.start = function (id,name){
     $('#chat').show();
     $('#chatHeader').html(name);
     socket.emit('startchat', name);
  }


  $('#send').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //empeche la page de se recharger
    var msg = $('#message').val();
     if(msg !== ''){
      socket.emit('message', msg);
         }
   $('#message').val('');

   });
  });

  socket.on('msg', function(msg){
    $('.messages').append('<div>'+ msg + '</div>');
  });





 });
```

Comment: Could you please reformat the indenting of your code with spaces instead of tabs? It's pretty hard to read. Also, it looks like you have a stray `/` in your server code, about halfway through on line 86: `room.forEach(function(room){ /`.

Comment: That's done, I fixed the '/' error, and tried to fix the indenting